# Anorm return a list of dates

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm using the PlayFramework with Anorm to get a list of dates stored in my database :

```
 def getDatesFromDB(): List[Array[String]] = {


    db.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("Select [dateStart] from [dbo].[dates]").as(scalar[Array[String]].*);

    }

  }
```

But how i can get a List with DateTime format knowing that my dates are stored in a date type ? ex : 2016-02-11

At the end i want to have a list like that :

```
  new DateTime("2016-01-17"),
    new DateTime("2016-01-20"),
    new DateTime("2016-01-23"),
     ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format DateTime in scala, just use method `toString` like this

```
val myDate = DateTime.now()
val myFormatDate = myDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

As for your question, you can firstly get the result as Array[DateTime], then change the DateTime to the format you want.

```
def getDatesFromDB(): List[Array[String]] = {

    val result_tmp = db.withConnection { implicit c =>
        SQL("Select [dateStart] from [dbo].[dates]").as(scalar[Array[String]].*)
    }
// Referred to your code, the type of result_tmp should be List[Array[DateTime]]
// we can format it as you want with the following code

    val result = result_tmp.map { item =>
        item.map { myDate => myDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
    }

   result
}
```

Good luck